# ¿Por qué al bajar un archivo con wget luego no lo encuentra?

Tags: bash, wget

Intenté crear mi primero chatbot por mi propio con la ayuda de Rasa y [este tutorial](https://chatbotslife.com/rasa-nlu-on-aws-28d962acbf53). Sin embargo me pide descargar Anaconda3 y hacer cosas que no compriendo y no funciona con Anaconda2

> Descargar Anaconda3-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh usando
>
> ```
>     wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda2-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
> ```
>
> Haz el siguiente comando
>
> ```
>     bash Anaconda2–4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
> ```

```
$ wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda2-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
--2018-05-10 16:11:45--  https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda2-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
Resolving repo.continuum.io (repo.continuum.io)... 104.16.18.10, 104.16.19.10, 2400:cb00:2048:1::6810:120a, ...
Connecting to repo.continuum.io (repo.continuum.io)|104.16.18.10|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 484472684 (462M) [application/x-sh]
Saving to: ‘Anaconda2-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh.1’

Anaconda2-4.3.1-Lin 100%[===================>] 462,03M  4,34MB/s    in 1m 55s  

2018-05-10 16:13:41 (4,01 MB/s) - ‘Anaconda2-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh.1’ saved [484472684/484472684]

$ bash Anaconda2–4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash: Anaconda2–4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh: No such file or directory
$ ls
alt_requirements                 docker                     rasa_nlu.egg-info
Anaconda2-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh  docs                       README.md
Anaconda3-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh  entrypoint.sh              requirements.txt
app.json                         heroku                     sample_configs
build                            LICENSE.txt                setup.cfg
CHANGELOG.rst                    Makefile                   setup.py
cloudbuild.yaml                  MANIFEST.in                test_models
CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md               MITIE-models               tests
data                             MITIE-models-v0.2.tar.bz2
dist                             rasa_nlu
```

¿Puedo omitir este paso?

Porque cuando lo omito y que hizo el commando que sigue,

```
$ conda install scikit-learn
conda: command not found
```

Comment: ¿Pero has hecho lo de `wget ...`? Esto baja un fichero "Anaconda2-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh", que es el que luego debes ejecutar. Ahora mismo este fichero no lo tienes, de ahí que te dé error.

Comment: @fedorqui Si, lo hicé. Actualicé el mensaje de error

Comment: se te está guardando con un nombre raro. Haz `bash *Anaconda2-4.3.1-Linux*` y seguramente funcionará, pues detectará aquel fichero que contenga este valor.

Comment: @fedorqui Ja, sí? ¡No sabía que me estaba protegiendo de ninguna manera! ¿Pero qué debería hacer? ¿Qué comando debería lanzar?

Comment: Pero existe ahora el fichero?

Comment: @fedorqui, si agregué la salida de `ls`

Comment: OK. Ahora es cuestión de ejecutarlo. ¿Te funciona?

Comment: @fedorqui si ! Cunado lo ejecuto, luego después de darle los derechos, funciona

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¡Se trata de un error en el artículo, que te hace ejecutar un archivo que no existe!

Cuando haces: `wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda2-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh` se está guardando el fichero `Anaconda2-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh`.

Luego el manual dice:

> Haz el siguiente comando
>
> ```
> bash Anaconda2–4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
> ```

Y esta segunda cadena utiliza un guion diferente después de "Anaconda2":

```
Anaconda2-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
Anaconda2–4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Fíjate:

```
-   # ASCII 2D
–   # ASCII 2013
```

Por tanto, es cuestión de escribir `bash Anaconda2` y luego darle al tabulador para que te complete el nombre.

---

También podrías bajar el fichero y llamarlo de otra forma. Esto es posible con la opción `-O` de wget:

```
wget https://unaweb/unarchivo.zip -O asi_lo_llamo_yo.zip
```

---

Alternativamente, puedes utilizar la expansión de parámetros y decir:

```
bash *Anaconda*.sh
```

lo que buscará todos los archivos que cumplan este patrón y los ejecutará. Huelga decir que no es muy recomendable, pues si hay unos cuantos puedes liarla.

Comment: he pinchado en votar tu respuesta por error y soy incapaz de retirar el voto, o te doy negativo o positivo, ¿qué prefieres?

Comment: @track3r hola! pues lo que tú prefieras. Si es un tema que no conoces, votar la respuesta sin saber si es correcta puede ser raro. He hecho una edición pequeña para que tu voto se desbloquee y puedas deshacerlo si quieres.

Comment: AAAh ya está, era darle arriba otra vez :) estoy algo tontico hoy... esque no estoy muy de acuerdo con lo que dices de las comillas, eso creo que es el escape, pero en el ls, se ve claro que no hay comillas.

Comment: @track3r tienes razón, y de hecho haciendo `wget google.com` veo que este es el texto que da wget → `2018-05-11 10:04:28 (1,71 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [12512]`. De todos modos, el `ls` lista dos ficheros con este nombre, luego parece como que haya algún tipo de carácter que no vemos. Máxime cuando en los comentarios sugerí lo de `bash *Anaconda*.sh` y le funcionó.

Comment: Ok, hay dos ficheros casi iguales y difieren del número "Anaconda2" y "Anaconda3", pero vamos, que eso no resuelve nada :)

Comment: Digo que mi aclaración de que uno se llama Anaconda2 y el otro Anaconda3 no resuelve el problema de OP. Tu respuesta si ;)

Comment: @track3r aaah vale, ahora entiendo.

Comment: @track3r ¡ya está! El texto de la web dice _Haz el siguiente comando

    `bash Anaconda2–4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh`_ y resulta que el guioncillo después de Anaconda es diferente del que hay en el servidor: _–_ y _-_.

Answer (score 0):

¿Estás seguro que has descargado el archivo correcto y que lo ejecutas desde el directorio correcto? en la [documentación de instalación de Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux) indican que la versión de Anaconda3 es para Python 3.6 y Anaconda2 para Python 2.7 y veo que escribes sobre descargar Anaconda3 poniendo un enlace de la versión 2.

Comment: Sí, pienso que descargado el archivo correcto y que lo ejecuto desde el directorio correcto. Agregué el mensaje de error que lo demuestra, creo

Comment: En comparación con su comentario sobre la descarga de Anaconda 3 mientras daba comandos para descargar Anaconda 2, es cierto que es extraño, pero puede verificarlo en el tutorial.